# how to trigger a backend node/express function from the frontend?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I don't understand how to send a request from my frontend with jquery to the backend for triggering the function that should search the db and delete/update a document. I just want to press a button and delete/update a document. Everything works fine If I submit the requests via Postman. I'm a beginner with node and I couldn't find a solution.

**app.js**

```js
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(400).send();
  }
  Blog.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((docs) => {
    res.status(200).send({docs})
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400)
  });
});

app.patch('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id
  var update = {autore: req.body.autore}
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    res.status(400).send()
  } Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {new: true}).then((docs) => {
      res.send({docs});
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400)
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Titolo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button id:"cancella" type="submit">Submit</button

    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does this script.js file have to be managed also by backend?

Thank you in advance!

**script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#cancella').on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: '/delete/:id',
   type: 'DELETE',
   data: {"_id": 5984f1a8d2c11b0354d1601b},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
   console.log('Dati cancellati!' + data);
  }});
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `jQuery` you are sending `id` in its `body` but in `node` you are getting in your `query parameters`..

you should change your `jQuery` url and you don't need to send any `body`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#cancella').on("click", function() {
  var baseURL = 'http://localhost' // depending of your config you should set this
  $.ajax({
   url: baseURL + '/delete/' + 5984f1a8d2c11b0354d1601b,
   type: 'DELETE',
   success: function(data) {
   console.log('Dati cancellati!' + data);
  }});
 });
});
```

This should do the trick

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, with my baseURL 'http://192.168.0.4:3000' and any other id. It seems that the browser don't send any request :(